# TypeError using zoom and zoomToFit

Tags: javascript, flash, cytoscape-web

I am using Cytoscape Web 1.0.2 and am trying to zoom the visualization using

```
vis.zoom(0.5);
```

or

```
vis.zoomToFit();
```

However, I get the following error from calling `zoom`

```
TypeError: a.zoomTo is not a function
```

Here is the zoom function (from cytoscapeweb.min.js)

```
zoom:function(){
    var a=this.swf();
    if(arguments.length>0){
        a.zoomTo(arguments[0]);
        return this
    }else{
        return a.getZoom()
    }
}
```

And here is the error from `zoomToFit`

```
TypeError: this.swf().zoomToFit is not a function
```

and the method itself

```
zoomToFit:function(){
    this.swf().zoomToFit();
    return this
}
```

What's going on here? I am using Ubuntu 12.04, Firefox 15.0, and Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202.

On Chrome with Shockwave Flash 11.3 r31 the errors become

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'zoomTo'
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'zoomToFit'
```

Using Windows I get the same errors, so it is not OS related. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying it on local machine ? i mean you are working with local html files.
If so you need to specify security policy here http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html
for folder from you a trying to run you files. Add location and refresh page